# Sending Geolocation from a Web Application even when the tab is not in focus?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I want to be able to report a user's geolocation from my web application even when the tab the application is not in focus. The issue that I am having is that reporting does not happen when the tab is not in focus.

I have tried a couple of things:

First I used `setTimeout()`; however, this only counts when the application tab is in focus.

Second, I tried using HTML5 Web Workers to time the event, sending a message back to my main script every 5 seconds to report the users location. However, if I am reporting their location every 5 seconds and go to another tab for 20 seconds, when I return to the tab with my application running, 4 messages get sent at the same time and this is because although the web worker will run in the background, the main thread will not.

Finally, I tried implementing geolocation in the web worker. However, this doesn't have access to the `navigator.geolocation()` function and so didn't work either.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to?

Comment: Not possible on chromium based browsers. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506435. On firefox it works just fine

Comment: Hi Haych, you asked this question a year ago. Were you able to get this or some other alternative working?  They mention geolocation in a Service Workers specs... Not sure if anyone implemented that..

Comment: Hi Vitaly, I didn't ever get this working. At the time is was impossible and I haven't worked on it since (it was a group project at university and I have finished that now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gaby has said, this isn't possible on Chromium-based browsers. See comment above.